# Limit build to run only in specific time domain in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I have a build with a `finish build trigger` and i want to limit it to run only in specific time domain (e.g. between 4 AM to 5 AM) regardless to the `finish build trigger`, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to [pause build configuration](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Configuration#BuildConfiguration-BuildConfigurationState). You can pause build configuration using [REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API).

Comment: So i need to implement a scheduled code that will pause and start the build each day?

Comment: Yes, if you want to trigger builds only in special time window - when build configuration is active. Also here is the related request in TeamCity tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17581, please vote for it.

Comment: Also since **TeamCity 9.1** Scheduled build trigger can behave as Finished build trigger. It has got an ability to watch for builds in other build configurations and trigger a build if these builds change. More on this [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Hajipur+9.1+EAP1+%28build+35957%29+Release+Notes#Hajipur9.1EAP1%28build35957%29ReleaseNotes-Scheduletriggerimprovements).

Comment: It's not the solution i was expecting but it's the best (until now...). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the finish build trigger and add an extra step to the triggering build which calls the [rest api](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-TriggeringaBuild).

By adding a bit of logic around the call the check the time is in the required range, you should be able to achieve what you are after.

Comment: Indeed that will do the job, thanks. I hoped for a build in teamcity solution for it...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cron-like` expressions to write **schedule triggers** that will trigger your build at customized times. You can read the teamcity specs [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+Schedule+Triggers#ConfiguringScheduleTriggers-ScheduleTriggeroptions)

For example , if you want to run a target everyday at 4.30 AM , you would have to define it in the following syntax.

```
Seconds         0
Minutes         30
Hours           4
Day-of-month    *
Month           *
Day-of-week     ?
```

Comment: Maybe i didn't understood your solution, but i don't need a schedule.. i need to limit the other trigger to a certain time domain.